# Disable CertificateRequest in ServerHello in MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ssl

I configured SSL (not mutual SSL) in MySQL. I created a user like this.

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'passowrd'; 
GRANT ALL ON db_name.* TO 'username'@'%' REQUIRE SSL;
```

But, in `ServerHello`, I get this.

```
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS
Cert Authorities:
<Empty>
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 9
0000: 0D 00 00 05 02 01 02 00   00                       .........
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 02 00 04                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
localhost-startStop-1, READ: TLSv1.1 Handshake, length = 4
*** ServerHelloDone
```

This forces the client to send the client certificate. Since I don't want mutual SSL, I want to avoid this.

Basically, I want to remove `CertificateRequest` part from `ServerHello`. Is there a way to achieve this by some confguration? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could revoke SSL from the user in one of two ways:

### METHOD #1 : Recreate User without `REQUIRE SSL`

```
DROP USER IF EXISTS 'username'@'%';
CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'passowrd'; 
GRANT ALL ON db_name.* TO 'username'@'%';
```

### METHOD #2 : Hack `mysql.user`

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET ssl_type='' WHERE user='username' AND host='%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

## CAVEAT

Check release notes on MariaDB concerning `METHOD #2`.

I think there is a bug doing `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` in older versions.

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!